# CreateDataFrame or SaveAsTable intuitively encode in pyspark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a table in spark1.6 using pyspark. All of the tables columns are saved as text, I'm wondering if I can change this:

```
product = sc.textFile('s3://path/product.txt') 
product = m3product.map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
product = sqlContext.createDataFrame(product, ['productid', 'marketID', 'productname', 'prod'])
product.saveAsTable("product", mode='overwrite')
```

Is there something in the last 2 commands that could automatically recognize productid and marketid as numerics? I have a lot of files and a lot of fields to upload so ideally it would be automatic

Comment: maybe passing a Schema?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something in the last 2 commands that could automatically recognize productid and marketid as numerics

If you pass `int` or `float` (depending on what you need) pyspark will convert the data type for you.

In your case, changing the lambda function in

```
product = m3product.map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
product = sqlContext.createDataFrame(product, ['productid', 'marketID', 'productname', 'prod'])
```

to

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

def split_product_line(line):
    fields = line.split('\t')

    return Row(
        productid=int(fields[0]),
        marketID=int(fields[1]),
...
    )

product = m3product.map(split_product_line).toDF()
```

You will find it much easier to control data types and possibly error/exception checks.

[Try to prohibit lambda functions](http://www.pybloggers.com/testing-with-apache-spark-and-python/) if possible :)

Comment: thank you for this. Would you mind expanding a bit on the ... under the productid? do I do char(fields[0]) for character fields or is this just numerics? I tried to find documentation on this but was unable to.

Comment: See my edit. `split` gives strings so you don't need to do conversion if you just want strings, e.g., `productname=fields[2]`